# How to replace the c-q and c-s bindings for xon/xoff in Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

While using screen, I use in some application (ne, Nice Editor, to edit text files) the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> bindings.

But these keys are bound to xon/xoff commands.

How could I replace these bindings, with (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>&</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>"</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>) modifying the .screenrc configuration file ?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to disable the flow control.

So to avoid <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> and  <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> to be blocked by screen, one need to disable flow control.

This can be done using the `flow off` command while screen is running.

This can also be configured in the `.screenrc` file:

```
defflow off
```

This is sufficient and no other binding (or un-binding) are necessary.